# Can you add two non-mirrored disks to a zfs pool?

Tags: zfs

Is there a way to do something like this?

zpool create newpool raidz /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2 ( /dev/disk3 + /dev/disk4 )

Assuming disk1 and disk2 are larger, and disk3 and 4 are smaller.

You can get the end result (presumably with a performance hit) by creating and mounting a pool with disk3 and 4, then creating a single large file on that, then doing

zpool create raidz /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2 /disk3and4/somebigfile

But I was wondering if that can be done directly.

I'm on Ubuntu.

EDIT

Matt's comment is correct; I want to create a raidz of three devices: a disk, a disk, and (two disks mushed together to form a bigger disk).

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I can't really figure out what you're trying to do; but I suspect the answer is "it can be done", and we have plenty of ZFS experts wandering around.

Comment: Wow, that's hard to read!

Comment: Can you guys be more specific about what's hard to understand?  After thinking about it, I still can't figure out why it's not clear.

Comment: it is a bit hard to read. It sounds like you want to make a raidz from 3 disks, where  the 3rd disk is two small disks 'stuck' together. What OS are you using?

Comment: @USDMatt - yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And whats the operating system?

Comment: 3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu, but does it matter?  I thought most zfs admin stuff is similar or identical across platforms.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this directly in ZFS. For example, on FreeBSD, you can use `gconcat` to create a virtual device that concatenates the two disks. It may be possible to do a similar thing on Linux (possibly using LVM) but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Personally (although it depends on how critical the data is) I would prefer to keep things simple and either use a simple raid10/mirror setup - `zpool create pool mirror bigdisk1 bigdisk2 mirror smalldisk1 smalldisk2` or get another disk that matches disk 1 & 2.

Comment: @usdmatt you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant include a vdev in a vdev i'm afraid.